# How to avoid consecutive button clik for same button in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i want to avoid click event again on the same button continuously (i.e) consecutively click on same button

whether its possible or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible  in differents ways :

1) First method : use a boolean variable and update it when you want :

```
boolean isClickable = true;
Button btn;
// other declarations..
```

**// in the onCreate method :**

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**`onClick()` method :**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  if(isClickable) {
      //this code will be executed only when you set the boolean isClickable to true
//your code here
  }
}
```

And when you want to desactivate you click button ; just set the boolean to false :

isClickable = false;

2) Second method :

there is a method on View which will let your button non Clickable ; and then desactivate the listener on your Button so no Object will listen the event click on your button like this :

```
 btn.setClickable(false);
    btn.setOnClickListener(null);
```

***NB :*** when you want to turn your button clickable again , just set the listener to this and make it clickable again ( for the Second Method ) :

```
btn.setClickable(true);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

or just update the value of the boolean isClickable (for the first method)

```
isClickable = true;
```

Comment: if i want to click the button again after two more some other click mean it will work or not..if work means which method will work @Houcine

Comment: both of methods will works , just when you want to desactivate the click on button you will do just like i said in my answer, and after two more some other click on ever what you want, you can activate the click event on your button by using code in answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set the onClickListener to null when you want to disable handling of this event, and set it back to the same listener you've had before in order to re-enable it .

of course , there are many solutions for this as Houcine has written .